# Template in main function using parametrized constructor

Tags: c++

I have created template following class

```
template <class T,int MAX_SIZE>
class XYZ{
public:

    XYZ(); // default constructor, construct an empty heap
    XYZ(T* items, int size);// construct a heap from an array of elements
```

I have tried to call like this but its giving following error

Invalid arguments.

```
private:
    int _size; // number of queue elements
    T _array[MAX_SIZE];
```

I want to copy the value of items in array..

what should be the constructor call in c++.I am trying like this.

```
int a[10]={32,31,.............};
PQueue<int[] ,10> q0;
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a [MCVE] as required please?

Answer (score 1):

the default call should be: (according to your signatures up there)

```
XYZ<int,10> var;
```

the argument ctor call should look like this: (assuming a[10] exist and within scope)

```
 XYZ<int,10> var{a,10};
```

as for copying a values to var depends on the implementation of that ctor which depends on you.

Comment: in C++98 'q0' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'.I have done following                                                                                                    .int a0[4] = {39,40,67,78};
   XYZ<int ,4> q1{a0,4};

Comment: your compiler is old. so use XYZ<int,4> q1(a0,4); also notice that implies int a0[4]